# Check if chart is rendered in apexcharts

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am [destroying the chart](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#destroy) but when it's not rendered I get error.

Is there a way to check if chart is rendered, then destroy it?

```
if(chart)
chart.destroy()
```

Each time i destroy an object that does not exist i get **TypeError**: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Also i need to render it again if it's not rendered, i won't render it again and again. I need that check

Comment: can you provide your complete code and what error you are getting in console ?

Comment: I try to destroy an object that does not exist, because it's already destroyed. I get apexcharts error: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked documentation states that `render()` returns a promise once the chart is drawn to the page.

The code however seems to return that promise immediately (which makes sense) and resolves that promise, when the chart was drawn.
As far as I can see, it should be sufficient to set and keep a state-flag after the promise is resolved like so:

```
let chart = new ApexCharts(el, options);

chart.render().then(() => chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered = true);

/* ... */

if (chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered) {
    chart.destroy();
}
```

**Update after comment**

Yes this works! I made this runnable example for you (typically this is the duty of the person *asking* the question ;) ) Press the button and inspect the log):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>chart test</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
    <head>

    <body>

        <div id="chart"></div>

        <script>
            let options = {
                    chart: { type: 'line' },
                    series: [{ name: 'sales', data: [30,40,35,50,49,60,70,91,125] }],
                    xaxis: { categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999]}
                },
                chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options),
                logChart = () => console.log(chart),
                destroyChart = () => {
                    if (chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered) {
                        chart.destroy();
                        chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered = false;
                    }
                };

            chart.render().then(() => chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered = true);

        </script>

        <button onclick="logChart()">Log chart</button>
        <button onclick="destroyChart()">Destroy chart</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

I suspect that you tried something like this to check for the flag:

```
chart.render().then(() => chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered = true);
console.log(chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered);
```

It will not do what you expect because the promise is not resolved yet.

**Update after another comment**

As pointed out by a comment there is a related known issue with apexcharts:
https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/pull/415

Comment: When is destroyed i need to use `chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered - false` will it set it to  false?

Comment: It did not work. I console log `chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered` after chart is rendered but it returns undefined.

Comment: Unfortunately `destroy()` returns nothing useful. You can cross your fingers and set the state-flag to false after the call. I'd recommend to take a look at the source to see what is actually going on. Btw, in javascript we typically use the assignment operator `=` for assignments, not the `-`. So it should be `chart.ohYeahThisChartHasBeenRendered = false;` when you want to keep the name for the flag.

Comment: Yes, i meant to write `=` not `-`

Comment: I think the library itself should have taken in mind those issues. Render method should by default get executed when the corresponding chart is not already rendered

Comment: There are upsides and downsides with both approaches. You can get in touch with the authors if you have suggestions. They offer a forum and a github-repo.

Comment: This is a known bug in ApexCharts as described here - https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/pull/415. Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce it, hence the PR is still not merged. Can someone create a reproducible example on codesandbox?

Comment: @junedchhipa thank you for that hint. I was not aware of that bug. I'll add a reference to my answer.

Comment: @junedchhipa the bug you linked is based on react apexcharts? By the way  i do not get that error anymore, I did two things: I added `data: []` in the series since i add data to the chart using AJAX. Secondly, i did a workaround, i made a variable `chartRendered=false` and once is rendered i set it to true. Then i make an if `if not is rendered` then create the chart object and render it. For `destroy()` i use the same logic, i only destroy if chart is rendered. I also use `try-catch`

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question asks to "check if the chart is rendered", the code suggests that they actually want to "check if the chart exists". I would also like to check if a chart exists before rendering it, and I suspect this is the more common issue.

I'm not sure about the accepted answer here. It seems that this answer always creates a new chart, hence there is no need to check if the chart exists.

I worked on this for some time - got no help from documentations- and finally discovered the `Apex` object. Check out `Apex._chartInstances`: this field is undefined before any charts render, and as they render, they store references here. After at least one rendering, the length of this field is equal to the number of existing charts.

Check if any charts have ever existed: `(Apex._chartInstances === undefined)`

Check if any charts currently exist: `(Apex._chartInstances.length > 0)`

Access the id's of existing charts: `(Apex._chartInstances[0].id)`

These bits were enough to make it work for my case. Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: This helped me figure out this solution: https://github.com/styd/apexcharts.rb/discussions/88#discussioncomment-8185257

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the beforeMount and mounted [events](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/) to check if the chart was rendered or not. For some reason, I am not able to catch the error that ApexChart throws.

My logic:

in beforeMount, make a delayed call to error handler and set error flag to true.

in mounted, set error flag to false. When the error handler runs, if the error flag is false, you skip othwe

```
{
...
chart: {
  type: "scatter",
  height: height,
  events: {
    beforeMount: function (chartContext, config) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        PAGE_DATA.ShowChartError = true;
        showChartErrorMessage($(chartContext.el));
      }, 1000);
    },
    mounted: function (chartContext, config) {
      PAGE_DATA.ShowChartError = false;
    },
  },
},
...
}
```

Error handler,

```
function showChartErrorMessage($el) {
  if (PAGE_DATA.ShowChartError) {
    // show error msg
    $el.siblings(".error-help-container").removeClass("hidden");
    // hide chart div
    $el.hide();
  }
  PAGE_DATA.ShowChartError = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all sorts of suggestions on destroying a rendered chart and nothing seemed to work.  Finally I tried this and it worked.

Before you render it, put a destroy in a try catch with no error, basically an on error resume next and then render it.

```
var chart22 = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#row2-2"), options1);
try{
  chart22.destroy();
}
catch{
}
chart22 = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#row2-2"), options1);
chart22.render();
```